# JSON Array Request Parsing error using Volley Library

Tags: android, json

I'm working on a news application with api from newsapi.org. I'm using volley library for making JSONArrayRequest and getting data. I'm trying to get my head around json array and json object to understand the parsing. Unfortunately, I'm unable to parse the response. It always calls OnErrorResponse where the response is the json data. Can someone guide me how can I parse the response?

Response:
[image: Response]

URL to site:

```
  https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/sources
```

Parsing:

```
   public void jsoncall() {

JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_JSON, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            Log.d("OnResponse", "" + response);

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sources");
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + jsonObject1.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,anime.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lstAnime.add(anime);*/
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Size of Liste " + String.valueOf(lstAnime.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), lstAnime.get(1).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            setRvadapter(lstAnime);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.d("OnErrorResponse",""+error.toString());

        }
    });


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: Use Gson library for paring https://github.com/google/gson but first made you POJO of your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear you are receiving JSONObject include "status" and "sources". I suggest to call *JsonObjectRequest* 
Then parse your response to get JSONArray "sources" :response.getJSONArray("sources");